# Using GPU with multiclass in Catboost

Tags: python, catboost

I am trying to use catboost to predict multiclass, but I got an error as below.

```
Error: loss function is not supported for GPU learning MultiClass
```

I used catboost option as below.

```
CatboostClassifier(loss_function='MultiClass',task_type='GPU')
```

I wonder if I can use GPU to predict multiclassification.

Comment: In issue 228, the Catboost team claims this is available in the latest release which you can build from source: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/228

Comment: @BoboDarph I read that, but it does not work though I have the latest one..

Comment: You should build code from source using the instruction: https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/installation/python-installation-method-build-from-source-linux-macos-docpage/.
Or you can wait for a few days, when the new version will be published on pypi, it will be there in the middle of September in version 0.10.

Answer (score 2):

MultiClass is available for GPU catboost starting from version 0.10.0.